# SQL list into a range outcome

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, gaps-and-islands

Considering a situation where we are provided with a list of account ids (say a table with `account_id` field (integer)) which has account numbers as shown below:

```
account_id
   1001
   1002
   1003
   1008
   1009
   1010
   1011
   1050
   1051
```

I am trying to create query which will translate this list into a range.

So a range will comprise of continuous sequence of account numbers,for example, account id are continuous from 1001 to 1003, then 1008 to 1011, then 1050 to 1051.

I am trying to get the below output:

```
account_from    account_to
    1001           1003
    1008           1011
    1050           1051
```

I am stuck on this and no sure how to get the outcome needed.This is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b14c/1).

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic Gaps-and-Islands which can easily be solved via Row_Number()

Take a peek at the results of the subquery to better understand the methodology.

```
Select account_from = min([account_id])
      ,account_to   = max([account_id])
 From (
        Select * 
              ,Grp = [account_id] - row_number() over (Order by [account_id])
         From YourTable
      ) A
  Group By Grp
```

Returns

```
account_from    account_to
1001            1003
1008            1011
1050            1051
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try the query below:

```
Select 
  min(account_id) as account_from,
  max(account_id) as account_to 
from 
    (
      select 
        account_id,
        (account_id - row_number() over (Order by account_id))  as acc
      from test
     ) new 
 Group By acc
```